# Need return() to rerender when component updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The behaviour i am expecting when this component runs is when the current url changes, the useEffect will load the data and then display allRecipes, myRecipes or Createform depending on the current url. However, in the return method is stacking on top of each other. How do i have the return method to re-render with new loaded data without stacking on top of the previous loaded data?

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const [allRecipes, setAllRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [myRecipes, setMyRecipes] = useState([]);
  const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/global') {
      console.log('hello');
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getAllRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setAllRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    } else if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts') {
      console.log('hi');
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setMyRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    }
  }, [currentUrl]);
  console.log(allRecipes.length);
  console.log(myRecipes.length);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dashboard">
        <DashboardHeader />
        <div className="created-posts">
          {allRecipes.length !== 0
            ? allRecipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {myRecipes.length !== 0
            ? myRecipes.recipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {currentUrl === '/dashboard/create' ? <CreateForm /> : null}
          <LoadingIndicator />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter and you can have multiple useEffects if you want

Comment: Try reseting your state each time you fetch recipes depending on the URL.